MakeIndex cross reference "see|" does not work for more than one word
I want to cross reference phrases using MakeIndex. For one word cross referenced to one other word, there is no problem. If I try to cross reference more than one word, the reference does not appear. I have pasted a short file and results below.  Thanks for your help!
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}                
\geometry{letterpaper}                  
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{anysize}
\marginsize{.5in}{.4in}{.75in}{.75in} 

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}

\noindent First, a cat\index{cat}.  \\

Second, this is cat of nine lives\index{cat!of nine lives}.  \\

Third, the previous  cat also be called a cat of  more than eight lives\index{cat!of more than eight lives!|see{cat!of nine lives}}\index{cat!of nine lives}.  \\


\noindent  Also, try this: Funny\index{funny}, or, humorous\index{humorous|see{funny}}.  


\printindex  

\end{document}  

=====================
compiling via LATEX, MakeIndex, LATEX, produces the following:
First, a cat.
Second, this is cat of nine lives.
Third, the previous cat also be called a cat of more than eight lives.
Also, try this: Funny, or, humorous.
++++++++
Index
cat, 1 
of nine lives, 1
funny, 1
 humorous, see funny
===============
The MakeIndex console shows:
This is makeindex, version 2.15 [TeX Live 2020] (kpathsea + Thai support).
Scanning input file MakeindexExample.idx....done (5 entries accepted, 1 rejected).
Sorting entries....done (11 comparisons).
Generating output file MakeindexExample.ind....done (14 lines written, 0 warnings).
Output written in MakeindexExample.ind.
Transcript written in MakeindexExample.ilg.


There are two issues here.

see is not expected to add a page reference. Rather, it just adds something to the index as a cross-reference. Usually, I put all my sees for a document together at the beginning of the document. You don't have to do that, but it keeps things organised. These entries aren't connected to particular locations in your document directly. They only connect via the indexed items they reference. So the lack of a page number for the see entries is the normal behaviour.
The syntax of the eight-lives entry is wrong. You do not want a second exclamation mark before the |. Nor should you have one in the argument of see.

That is, the syntax should be
\index{cat!of more than eight lives|see{cat, of nine lives}}

If you do this the entries are all processed without error.
Incidentally, if you look in the .ilg file, it tells you both the line number of the error in your .idx, the nature of that error and the horizontal position of the error in that line. In general, the .ilg gives really very good directions for finding problems. In this case, you still might not have been sure why the extra !s were a problem, but you would have known that it was !s which were problematic and exactly where those !s were in the .idx. You would, however, probably have to go through two trouble-shooting cycles to determine this since the second erroneous ! occurs on the same line of the .idx as the first.
Corrected example:
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}                
\geometry{letterpaper}                  

% \usepackage{anysize}
% \marginsize{.5in}{.4in}{.75in}{.75in} 

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}

\noindent First, a cat\index{cat}.  \smallskip

Second, this is cat of nine lives\index{cat!of nine lives}.  \smallskip

Third, the previous  cat also be called a cat of  more than eight lives\index{cat!of more than eight lives|see{cat, of nine lives}}\index{cat!of nine lives}.  \smallskip


\noindent  Also, try this: Funny\index{funny}, or, humorous\index{humorous|see{funny}}.  


\printindex  

\end{document}  

Off-topic: don't use \\  to make paragraphs. It doesn't.
Also off-topic: don't use both anysize and geometry as they are just going to fight with each other. My strong recommendation would be to use geometry and set your margins using its interface, but if you must use anysize, you certainly shouldn't use geometry, too.
